# How can I implement an 'if' statement in an interpreter?

Tags: compiler, virtual-machine, interpreters

If I were writing a compiler (say for a stack-based VM), the code for an `if` statement:

```
if (<some_expression>)
{
    <some_instructions>
}
```

Would be translated to the following psuedo-assembly:

```
<evaluate expression and push result on stack>
JUMP-IF-TRUE label
<some_instructions>
:label
```

This is easy to implement in a compiler, however I'm not sure how to implement this in an interpreter.

The difference between an interpreter and a compiler, is that a compiler outputs instructions to be performed later, and an interpreter performs right away.

So e.g. instead of outputting the instruction `PUSH`, an interpreter would simply `PUSH` on a stack it maintains. And so on.

So regarding `JUMP` instructions (such as the `JUMP-IF-TRUE` psuedo-instruction), I guess my question is how are these implemented in interpreters?

More accurately, how can I make an interpreter 'jump' over a piece of code, for example when interpreting an `if` statement?

Comment: Usually using the `if` of the host language, executing (or skipping) interpreter input as appropriate.

Comment: It depends entirely on what the interpreter interprets. Bytecode? AST? God forbid, lines of source code?

Comment: I would be hard-pressed to name a modern interpreter that works this way. Even if not compiling to machine code, the idea of [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is very pervasive. Even if the compiled form is simply kept in memory and not stored in an executable file, interpreters will still compile scripts.

Comment: @Snowman You seem to be confusing something. Hardly anything that goes by the term JIT compiler stores the generated code in files. The real distinction is that JIT compilers generate machine code to be executed by the CPU while the interpreters you seem to be talking about generate some sort of byte code that is then interpreted by a virtual machine/interpreter. Totally different target language and performance characteristics and technical difficulties and architecture.

Comment: @delnan correct. My point was it is the same idea: compilation steps going on at run time. It is conceptually similar.

Comment: Not that it would matter a lot for this discussion but your pseudo-assembly should `JUMP-IF-FALSE`.

Answer (score 6):

As a picture is worth a thousand words, let's write an interpreter together! Of course, a very simple one. We use OCaml for this, but if you do not know OCaml, this is fine, because we will write very little code and comment it anyway.

We first define what is a program for us. We consider a very simple language, allowing to print text, add numbers, and test if a number is zero with an if-statement:

```
type statement =
| Print of string
| If of expr * statement * statement
| Sequence of statement list
and expr =
| Constant of int
| Plus of expr * expr
```

The code above is a *type declaration* and defines what our idea of a program is. It defines an abstract symbolic form for programs – as opposed to the concrete tetual form – which is easy to manipulate in OCaml. This type definition is a plain translation of the english description of what a program is, with the addition of a sequence, to execute more operations.  (If we remove the `Plus` and the `Sequence` operations we pretty much obtain the smallest possible language demonstrating an `If` statement, but I felt it could be a bit too boring!)

**Real life note** In real life, a program contains a lot of annotations. An  important one is that program elements are typically annotated with their location in termes of file, line, column, which is useful to report errors.

We can already write an entertaining program in our language:

```
let program = Sequence([
  Print("Hello, world!");
  If(Plus(Constant(1),Constant(0)),
    Print("One is the truth"),
    Print("One is a lie"));
  Print("Oh, that was a tough one!");
])
```

This should print the text `Hello, world!` to please Dennis, then compute 1 + 0 and compare the result to 0 – as for the definition of `If` in our language - if the result is distinct from 0, then the first branch is executed and the perlish message `One is the truth` is printed, otherwise the also perlish message `One is a lie` is printed. After such a tough challenge, our strained computer will share its feelings `Oh, that was a tough one!`.

**Real life note** In the real world, one needs to write a parser to translate plain text into an abstract program as the one held by the variable `program`. We can use **lex** and **yacc** for this, and their various derivatives.

Now let us write an interpreter for our language. (If you felt asleep, wake up now, the actual answer to the question will soon be presented!)

```
let rec interpreter = function
| Sequence(hd::tl) -> interpreter hd; interpreter(Sequence(tl))
| Sequence([]) -> ()
| Print(message) -> print_endline message
| If(condition, truebranch, falsebranch) ->
    (* The answer to the question is here! *)
    if (eval condition) <> 0 then
      interpreter truebranch
    else
      interpreter falsebranch
and eval = function
| Constant(c) -> c
| Plus(a,b) -> (eval a) + (eval b)
```

Most of us are likely not familiar with OCaml, so let us walk gently through this piece of code:

```
let rec interpreter = function
| Sequence(head::tail) -> interpreter head; interpreter(Sequence(tail))
   (* To interpret a list of statements, we interpret the first
      and then interpret the tail of the list. *)

| Sequence([]) -> ()
   (* To interpret an empty list of statements, we just do nothing.
      Fair enough, right? *)

| Print(message) -> print_endline message
    (* To print a message, we use the host-language printing facility. *)

| If(condition, truebranch, falsebranch) ->
    (* The answer to the question is here!

       We first evaluate the condition, with the eval function below
       and use the host-language if facility to take the decision
       of recursively calling the interpreter on the truebranch or
       the falsebranch. *)

    if (eval condition) <> 0 then
      interpreter truebranch
    else
      interpreter falsebranch

and eval = function
| Constant(c) -> c
    (* Constants evaluate to themselves *)
| Plus(a,b) -> (eval a) + (eval b)
    (* A Plus statement evaluates to the sum of its parts. *)
```

Now let's execute the program:

```
let () = interpreter program
```

which causes the output

```
Hello, world!
One is the truth
Oh, that was a tough one!
```

It you want to try it, just copy the program snippets in a file `interpreter.ml` and run with **ocaml** from your shell prompt:

```
% ocaml imterpreter.ml
```

**Conclusion** When we write an interpreter using an intermediate abstract representation of the program like in this small example. The `If` statement is easily implemented in terms of conditionals in the host language. Other strategies are possible, it is perfectly imaginable to compile the program “on the fly” and to feed it to a virtual machine. (Some people will argue that there is essentially no difference between the two approaches.)

Answer (score 5):

If your language is truly interpreted (i.e., it executes statements as encountered and doesn't convert the entire program into a data structure once at startup), there are two ways for the interpreter to handle conditions:

**Explicit Jump.**  Languages like BASIC that aren't much of a step up from assembly require that the program explicitly say where to go next:

```
10 REM 1970S-VINTAGE BASIC
20 IF A <> 5 THEN 40
30 PRINT "A IS 5"
40 PRINT "DOING THE NEXT THING"
```

The `THEN` clause in line `20` is an explicit jump.  The hardware running assembly (well, machine code) would handle this by jumping to an address in memory; interpreted BASIC handles it by searching the program for the destination line number.

You can see this in action in the [source code for Applesoft BASIC](http://www.txbobsc.com/scsc/scdocumentor/D912.html), where statements are tokenized as they're keyed in but execution still works as if they're being interpreted individually.  The `IF` statement (handled at address `D9C9`) evaluates the expression and, if true and the `THEN` clause is a line number, executes a `GOTO` (address `D9E6`).  The GOTO code (at `D93E`) searches ahead from the current line if the destination line is greater or from the top of the program if not.

**Block Skip.**  Languages with more structure put a restriction on direct jumps as part of an `if` statement by requiring that execution continue only in a forward direction* and that there be something to indicate that the end of the statements to be executed if true has been reached.  Some languages do this with block markers (e.g., `BEGIN...END` or `{...}`); others, like the Bourne shell, have a marker for identifying the end of the "true" block that's if-statement-specific:

```
# Bourne Shell
if [ "$A" eq 5 ]
then
  echo "A was 5"
fi
echo "Doing the next thing"
```

If the test result is `false`, the interpreter will expect and swallow a `then` statement and then continue reading lines without actually executing any of them until one that has some control significance to the `if` (anything but `else`, `elsif` and `fi`) is encountered.  Note that while modern versions of the Bourne shell will attempt to interpret the statements within the block for syntactical correctness, a naive implementation could simply ignore the contents until reaching an `else`, `elsif` or `fi` with no effect on how the program executes.

---

*Backwards is allowed using only language-provided looping constructs or the ever-frowned-upon `goto`.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because you actually provided proof (The Applesoft BASIC source code is still available?  Who knew?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Commented, no less.  That source isn't the original, but it's an excellent teaching tool.  I'd love to find something similar for CP/M.  Edit:  [well, that was easy](http://www.retroarchive.org/cpm/archive/unofficial/source.html).

Answer (score 3):

(NOTE: there are other ways of doing things.  I am describing a simple way.  This is NOT the most efficient way.  Real interpreters use all sorts of tricks to save time)

When running a compiled program, the processor have a Program Counter that tells it which part of the program it is executing.  The machine code JMP instruction sets the PC to a new value and the processors starts executing the corresponding part of the program

When you make an interpreter, you need to have a variable that corresponds to the Program Counter.  This variable will point to some place in the source program. Let us call this variable IPC.

When you come to an `if`  and need to skip the body, you have to look through the source code for the end.  In the example you give, you need to look for the ending `}`.  When you have found it just set IPC to the next location and you are good to go.

On a modern processor, you also have a stack which is where a machine code program will store information about subroutine parameters, return addresses and local variables.

In an interpreter you will probably need to store similar information on one or more stacks or other data structures.  This will be independent of the machine code stack.

Loops are complicated, you either need to keep information about them in another data structure of search backwards for the loop start.

Doing all this in a simple way will be *slow*.  If you encounter the same `if` again you will need to search through the code again.

Real interpreters add lots of time saving tricks.  The interpreter becomes much faster, but also much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Any interpreter worth its salt does not "execute" the source code directly.  Rather, it executes some other internal representation of the source code, like an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST).

When your program is loaded, the parser makes a quick pass through the source code to turn the source into its corresponding internal form.  This can be done very quickly.  Once the source is in an AST, it will already contain jump instructions that point directly to specific addresses.  This alleviates the need to parse the source during execution until you find the target label for the jump.

Comment: Tokenized as in lexical analysis? I don't know a single interpreter that does that, they all use an AST at least.

Comment: P-code, basically.

Comment: P-code is bytecode. That's something entirely different from tokens.

Comment: Never mind then.  Essentially, you map keywords of the language to subroutines.  That's how I understood what they called the p-code in VB6 and VBA to work.  I associate AST's with compilers, not interpreters; the [Wikipedia article on AST's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) never mentions interpreters, though it's perfectly feasible to generate one for an interpreter.

Comment: Yes, most interpreters actually interpret bytecode, but some do take their parser's AST and interpret it rather than generating bytecode from it. None of that has anything to do with tokens, so your terminology is really confusing. Most bytecode formats (including what I gleaned from p-code) is more complicated than just turning each occurence of a keyword to a call to the corresponding subroutine, though.

Comment: Well, I'm using the term "tokens" colloquially.  I'll change the terminology to AST; you can do the same with one of those.

Comment: @delnan: Ah, so my "tokens" description [was right after all](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/283413/1204) (though I was apparently wrong about VB).